# How to get post meta from a wordpress page to another?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have an about page in wordpress, I wanted its content to appear in the home page, I managed to do that using this code that I found through searching

```
<?php
$my_id = 256;
$post_id_256 = get_post($my_id);
$content = $post_id_256->post_content;
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
$content = str_replace(']]>', ']]>', $content);
echo $content; 
?>
```

That works perfect. Now the page also has a costume field with I nee to also get - I tried to manipulate the above code (specially lines 2 and 3) but I cant get the costume field

Hope you can help

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get custom fileds with [get_post_meta()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta), like so:

```
<?php
$custom_field = get_post_meta(256, 'name_of_your_custom_field');
echo $custom_field;
?>
```

Comment: thanks, I just had to add true at the end e.g get_post_meta(256, 'name_of_your_custom_field', true); - thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Use below function to get the post's custom field values:

```
$meta_values = get_post_meta($post_id, $key);
```